# Is there a way to quickly add/remove a parent on the xml editor on Android Studio?

Tags: android

I was wondering if there's a shortcut to do this. I always manually remove each tag in the xml editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Go to xml editor `Design view > Component Tree tab >` you can find the list of all the xml elements and click and delete from there easily.